# how to check the tag name corresponds to specific tag in Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am parsing html file through all its tags and when I encounter body tag I want to perform some string operations and save the results back to html file. When I try

```
if tag.name == 'body':
  // go inside the loop
```

the if loop itself is not getting processed. What is the correct method to check whether the tag name corresponds to body tag

Comment: You could use the [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) module, which is made for parsing web html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer using beautifulsoup and would like to update it to others : Soup.body.name

Comment: If the tag is inside the body, yes. Otherwise `soup.your_tag`, like: `soup.head`, `soup.title`, ...